# How to access an object by key in javascript or typescript whithin an unknown key

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following object and I wonder how can I access the 'value' key.

```
{ '-L7uAVxXmuLeBN1K-B0_': { timestamp: '18:35:18', value: 19.81 } }
```

I don not know the first key the '-L7uAVxXmuLeBN1K-B0_', but it always has the same structure. Is there a way to achieve this with javascript or typescript?

Comment: `Object.keys()`?

Comment: but I don't know the first key, the one that contains the value. I need to do something like `variable.WILDCARD.value`

Comment: Use `Object.keys` and receive array of keys in your object, no?

Comment: `const unknownKey = Object.keys(yourObject)[0]`,
`const timestampObject = yourObject[unknownKey]`, `const value = timestampObject.value`

Comment: in short: `const value = yourObject[Object.keys(yourObject)[0]].value`

Comment: @Kox, you can place an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is!

```
const value = yourObject[Object.keys(yourObject)[0]].value
```

With a bit of description:

You can access the object's keys by using `Object.keys(obj)` method which returns an array of its keys. Since your object has only one key, access it via `Object.keys(obj)[0]`. That's the key you don't know.

Now you have your key, access the inner object first via **bracket notation**:

```
obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]
```

And then access your value!

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you very much! It was just what I needed, and thank you for the explanation too!